# Lua - Two local variables with the same name

Tags: variables, lua, undefined-behavior

I have been learning [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) and I was wondering if it is allowed to reference two local variables of the same name.

For example, in the following code segment, is the syntax legal (without [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))?

I ask because it does run, but I cannot seem to figure out what is happening behind the scenes.  Is this simply referencing the same `x` local?  Or are there now two `local x` variables that mess things up behind the scenes.  I'd like to know what exactly is happening here and why it is the case.

```
local x = 5 + 3; -- = 8
local x = 3 - 2; -- = 1

print("x = " .. x); -- x = 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two variables.  The second shadows (but does not remove or overwrite) the first.

Sometimes you can still access the earlier definition via a closure.

```
local x = 5 + 3
local function getX1()
  return x
end
local x = 3 - 2
local function getX2()
  return x
end

print("x = " .. x); -- x = 1
print("x = " .. getX1()); -- x = 8
print("x = " .. getX2()); -- x = 1
```

Answer (score 8):

All your local variables have been remembered by Lua :-)

```
local x = 5 + 3; -- = 8
local x = 3 - 2; -- = 1

local i = 0
repeat
   i = i + 1
   local name, value = debug.getlocal(1, i)
   if name == 'x' then
      print(name..' = '..value)
   end
until not name
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is legal. Lua handles `local`-variable declarations as `statements`.

Here's an interesting example from the [Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.5):

*Notice that each execution of a local statement defines new local variables. Consider the following example:*

```
 a = {}
 local x = 20
 for i=1,10 do
   local y = 0
   a[i] = function () y=y+1; return x+y end
 end
```

*The loop creates ten closures (that is, ten instances of the anonymous function). Each of these closures uses a different y variable, while all of them share the same x.*

In this example, if ignore the returning closure part, there are 10 `local` variables named `y` in the same `for` block.